# Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ be an ideal in $R$. Show that the quotient ring $R/I$ is commutative iff $xy-yx \in I$ for all $x,y \in R$.

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Here's what I tried.

$(\Rightarrow)$
Let $R/I$ be a commutative. Then, for all $(x+I),(y+I) \in R/I$, we have
\begin{align*}
(x+I)(y+I) &= (y+I)(x+I) \\
xy + I &= yx + I \\
xy - yx + I &= yx - yx + I \\
xy - yx + I &= I
\end{align*}
Hence, $xy-yx \in I$.

$(\Leftarrow)$
Let $x,y \in R$ and $xy-yx \in I$.
Then,
\begin{align*}
xy - yx + I &= I \\
xy + I + (-yx) + I = I \\
xy + I &= yx + I \\
(x+I)(y+I) &= (y+I)(x+I)
\end{align*}
Hence, $R/I$ is commutative.

Does above proof is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is right, but it can be shortened writing
\begin{align}
\forall x,y \in R : xy-yx \in I
\ \ & \Leftrightarrow \ \ 
\forall x,y \in R : (xy-yx)+I=I \\
\ \ & \Leftrightarrow \ \ 
\forall x,y \in R : (xy+I)-(yx+I)=I \\
\ \ & \Leftrightarrow \ \ 
\forall x,y \in R : xy+I = yx+I \\
\ \ & \Leftrightarrow \ \ 
\forall x,y \in R : (x+I)(y+I) = (y+I)(x+I) \\
\ \ & \Leftrightarrow \ \
\textrm{$R/I$ is commutative}
\end{align}

Comment: Great! That's so precise. Thanks a lot, Sir.